# Weak*-continuity of evaluation maps over open unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For a Banach space $X$. Is the following map weak*-continuous?

$$\phi: f\mapsto (u \mapsto f(u)),$$
where $u\in O_X$ and $O_X$ is the $\textit{open}$ unit ball of $X$? That is $\phi$ defines a map from $X^*$ to $\ell^\infty(O_X)$.

Obviously every $\phi_u: f\mapsto f(u)$, where $u$ is fixed, is weak*-continuous. But can we conclude that to a set of $u$? If the above is false, on what set can we conclude weak*-continuity?

Comment: Does $\ell^\infty(O_X)$ refer to the space of uniformly bounded functions on $O_X$? I would have used this notation for a sequence space, personally. If I'm correct, then does that mean you're looking at whether this map is weak$^*$-to-norm continuous, where the norm on the codomain is the supremum ($\infty$) norm?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, all of those are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The (supremum) norm of $u \mapsto f(u)$ is nothing but $\|f\|$. You are asking if $f_i \to f$ weak* implies $\|f_i-f\| \to 0$. This is ceratainly false.  For a  counter-example take $X$ to be a Hilbert space with an orhtonormal basis $(e_n)$. Then $e_n \to $ weak* but $\|e_n\|=1$ for all $n$.